# Newtonsoft JsonSchema.Parse failed

Tags: c#, json, json.net

here is my json schema file

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "BootNotificationResponse",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "status": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
            "Accepted",
            "Pending",
            "Rejected"
        ]
    },
    "currentTime": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date-time"
    },
    "interval": {
        "type": "number"
    }
},
"additionalProperties": false,
"required": [
    "status",
    "currentTime",
    "interval"
]
}
```

and I tried codes

```
        string file = File.ReadAllText(@"../../json/BootNotificationResponse.json");

        Console.WriteLine(file);

        JsonSchema.Parse(file);
```

file points json schema location.

there was exception.

```
 System.ArgumentException: Can not convert Array to Boolean.
```

I followed example code site Newtonsoft.

How can I solved this error?

please comment

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NewtonSoft's [Online Schema Validator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) and you will see "Required properties are missing from object: status, currentTime, interval." You will need to remove the following from your schema to make it work for this implementation.

```
"required": [
"status",
"currentTime",
"interval"
]
```

or if you want to fix it you will need to update the JSON schema to include the definitions like

```
 {
     '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
     'title': 'BootNotificationResponse',
     'definitions': {
         'BootNotificationResponse': {
             'type': 'object',
             'properties': {
                 'status': {
                     'type': 'string',
                     'enum': [
                         'Accepted',
                         'Pending',
                         'Rejected'
                     ]
                 },
                 'currentTime': {
                     'type': 'string',
                     'format': 'date-time'
                 },
                 'interval': {
                     'type': 'number'
                 }
             },
             'additionalProperties': false,
             'required': [
                 'status',
                 'currentTime',
                 'interval'
             ]
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed '}' put in json schema(editted) and i tried website with this json {
  "status": "Accepted",
  "currentTime": "2013-02-01T20:53:32.486Z",
  "interval": 300
} there was no error for me.

Comment: but still there is error with json schema that I posted in codes.

Comment: @user3773632 - I am not sure what you mean "there is error with json schema that I posted in codes". If you want your original schema to work you will need to remove the "required" property with it's associated array or you can use the schema provided that uses the "definitions" property to encapsulate the schema.